# Send message to content script from service worker

Tags: google-chrome-extension, plasmo

I am using [Plasmo](https://github.com/PlasmoHQ/plasmo) to create google chrome extensions.

My requirement is to invoke a function in a Content Script periodically. I tried to use `setInterval()` but this was not reliable. I read that using `chrome.alarms` service in the service worker is a better approach.

So, in my service worker, if I have the following code:

```js
// background/ports/timer.ts
import type { PlasmoMessaging } from "@plasmohq/messaging"

async function registerInitAlarm() {
  // Create an alarm that is invoked a second from now, for every 1.5 seconds
  await chrome.alarms.create("initialize", {
    when: Date.now(),
    periodInMinutes: 1
  })
}

const handler: PlasmoMessaging.PortHandler = async (req, res) => {
  const { type, message } = req.body

  if (type === "register") {
    await registerInitAlarm()
  }
}

chrome.alarms.onAlarm.addListener((alarm) => {
  if (alarm.name === "initialize") {
    // How do I send a message here to the content script?
  }
})

export default handler
```

As per the [documentation](https://docs.plasmo.com/framework/messaging#ports), I need to use ports API but it seems to be a request / response based API so it is not clear how I can send a message to the content script when an alarm triggers.

Alternatively, how do I send a message without the plasmo framework / api - because even the [regular chrome extension documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/messaging/) requires me to identify the tab first and then send a message to it (and there could be multiple tabs having my extension / content script)

Comment: You're looking for chrome.tabs.sendMessage with a tab id, but a better solution may be to use setInterval in the content script and then chrome.runtime.sendMessage or chrome.storage to get the data.

Comment: Did u get any solution?

Comment: No I did not find it. I recollect raising a discussion in the Plasmo repository too and no answer there as well :(